# Аномалии при работе с GridView

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток. Делаю сетку `GridView` для отображения уровней. 

**GridAdapter.java**

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Button> b = new ArrayList<>();
    private SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private String level_lock;

    public GridAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Button> b, SharedPreferences sharedPref) {
        mContext = c;
        this.b = b;
        this.sharedPref = sharedPref;
    }

    public interface Callback{
        void onClick(int position);
    }

    private Callback callback;

    public void setListener(Callback callback){
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return b.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Button button;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            button = new Button(mContext);
            button.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 200));
            button.setPadding(0, 40, 25, 0);
            //button.setScaleType(ImageButton.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        } else {
            button = (Button) convertView;
        }

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (callback != null) {
                    callback.onClick(position);
                }
            }
        });

        level_lock = sharedPref.getString("level_" + (position), "lock");
        if(level_lock.equals("unlock")) {
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_select);
            button.setEnabled(true);
            button.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTextSelect));
            Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "BuxtonSketch.ttf");
            button.setTypeface(typeface);
            button.setTextSize(40);
            button.setText(String.valueOf(position));
        }else {
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_lock);
            button.setEnabled(false);
        }
        return button;
    }
}
```

Этим адаптером заполняю сетку. Внизу кода в условии `if-else` я проверяю статус уровня в `SharedPreferences` и в зависимости от состояния устанавливаю кнопку: либо простую с цифрой уровня, если иначе то замочек без цифры и блокирую кнопку. Так вот если уровень `unlock`, то все нормально, а вот если отрабатывает `else` тут начинаются непонятицы: замочки на все кнопки устанавливаются нормально, НО на эти кнопки почему то проскакивают цифры уровня и некоторые редкие кнопки с замочками **не заблокированы**. "Непонятные" цифры устанавливаются из диапазона разблокированных уровней (например разблокированы 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, то только эти цифры разбросаны по замочкам). Более того, если я промотаю `GridView` вниз, а затем снова вверх, то цифры на замочках случайным образом уже меняются!

Подскажите пожалуйста, с чем могут быть связаны такие аномалии? Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы передаете в адаптер `ArrayList<Button> b`, но почему Вы его ни разу не используете в `getView(...)`?

Comment: И еще: вот возвратилось Вам старое `View` в виде `convertView`, если оно не `null`, то оно уже настроено. Например, Вам возвращается заблоченная кнопка, а Вы на ней потом цифры рисуете. То есть первоначальная ее позиция соответствовала заблокированному уровню, и все отрисовалось правильно, но когда требуется перерисовать список, то возвращается эта (уже настроенная кнопка), а Вы поверх нее рисуете цифру (так как текущая позиция соответствует назаблокированному уровню).

Comment: @post_zeew, к сожалению, я не силен в адаптерах. Возможно, коллекция там и не нужна. Видимо с неё берется только `.size()`. Установив просто число в `getCount()` отрабатывает то же самое.

Comment: @post_zeew, подскажите пожалуйста, как будет правильно модифицировать код?

Comment: Я могу что-то примерное накидать, но для `RecyclerView`. На смену `ListView` и `GridView` пришел `RecyclerView`, который, в зависимости от `LayoutManager` может отображать элементы как списком (как в `ListView`), так и таблицей (как в `GridView`). Эти устаревшие компоненты я не использую. Так что если Вас устроит решение с `RecyclerView` – напишите, что-то примерное тогда набросаю.

Comment: @post_zeew, конечно устроит, буду очень благодарен! Изучить что-то новое всегда хочется.  А я в проектах использую везде `ListView`...

Comment: Настоятельно советую Вам перейти на `RecyclerView`, он не сильно сложнее в изучении. Чуть позже набросаю код.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Проблема автора заключается в этом:

> И еще: вот возвратилось Вам старое `View` в виде `convertView`, если оно не `null`, то оно уже настроено. Например, Вам возвращается заблоченная кнопка, а Вы на ней потом цифры рисуете. То есть первоначальная ее позиция соответствовала заблокированному уровню, и все отрисовалось правильно, но когда требуется перерисовать список, то возвращается эта (уже настроенная кнопка), а Вы поверх нее рисуете цифру (так как текущая позиция соответствует назаблокированному уровню).

но из комментариев выяснилось, что автора устроит решение *с нуля*, поэтому публикую это как ответ.

Результат будет примерно таким:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Сначала определяемся с моделью данных**

На каких данных завязана логика адаптера? – на данных о доступности/недоступности уровня, следовательно, в качестве модели данных нас вполне устроит множество объектов с одним из двух возможных значений `true`/`false` – `ArrayList<Boolean>`.

**Теперь думаем как это все должно визуально выглядеть**

Визуальная составляющая у нас будет довольно примитивна, просто кнопка:

1. Если уровень доступен, то на кнопке будет написано `Unlocked`, если недоступен – `Locked`;
2. Если уровень доступен, то кнопка будет зеленого цвета, если недоступен – синего.

**Функционал? А как же без него**

Добавим чуть-чуть некоторой логики:

1. Если нажать на доступный уровень, то:

   - если он имеет **четный номер**, то добавим в таблицу (в конец) еще один **доступный уровень**;
   - если он имеет **нечетный номер**, то добавим в таблицу (в конец) еще один **недоступный уровень**;
2. При нажатии на недоступный уровень, выведем на экран уведомление с текстом «*Level locked!*».

*Эти действия я добавляю просто для примера, чтобы объяснить, как обрабатывать нажатия на соответствующие ячейки таблицы.*

**Пора начинать действовать**

**cell_item.xml** – `layout` (или эскиз) одной ячейки таблицы:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cell_item_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:textSize="10sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Тут все просто – обычная кнопка, обернутая в `LinearLayout`.

**main_activity.xml** – `layout` главного представления (в нем будет отображена таблица):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/grid_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Здесь тоже все просто – `RecyclerView`, обернутый в `LinearLayout`.

**Адаптер**, который будет управлять нашим `RecyclerView`:

```
public class GridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GridAdapter.CellViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<Boolean> mLevels;

    public GridAdapter(ArrayList<Boolean> levels) {
        mLevels = new ArrayList<>(levels);
    }

    @Override
    public CellViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cell_item, null);
        CellViewHolder cellViewHolder = new CellViewHolder(layoutView);
        return cellViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CellViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (mLevels.get(position)) {
            holder.mButton.setText("Unlocked");
            holder.mButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4AF764"));
        } else {
            holder.mButton.setText("Locked");
            holder.mButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7CC8F8"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mLevels.size();
    }

    public void addLevel(boolean isUnlocked) {
        mLevels.add(isUnlocked);
    }


    public class CellViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        public Button mButton;

        public CellViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cell_item_button);
            mButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!mLevels.get(getAdapterPosition())) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Level locked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                if (getAdapterPosition() % 2 == 0) { 
                    addLevel(true);
                } else {
                    addLevel(false);
                }
                notifyItemChanged(getItemCount() - 1);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

При создании экземпляра адаптера, мы будем передавать ему список `ArrayList<Boolean> levels`. Номер позиции элемента в списке будет равен номеру уровня, значение `true`, если уровень доступен и `false` в противном случае.

Ну и **MainActivity**, в котором я добавляю 10 доступных уровней и 15 недоступных:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    GridAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.grid_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 4));

        ArrayList<Boolean> levels = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            levels.add(true);
        }

        for (int i=0; i<15; i++) {
            levels.add(false);
        }

        mAdapter = new GridAdapter(levels);

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }
}
```

В Вашем случае нужно будет наполнять коллекцию `levels` в зависимости от данных, находящихся в `SharedPreferences`.

**UPD**. По поводу `ViewHolder`:

При запуске приложения, на экране Вы видите `40` ячеек таблицы (то есть `40` объектов `View`). На этом этапе создается `40` + еще несколько `View`, то есть для каждой ячейки вызывается метод `onCreateViewHolder(...)`, который создает `View`, и так же для каждой ячейки вызывается метод `onBindViewHolder(...)`, который заполняет ячейку **конкретными** данными.

После этого Вы пролистываете список вниз, при этом верхних ячеек уже не видно, зато появляются новые ячейки снизу. Так вот, чтобы не создавать новые `View` для ячеек, которые появляются на экране снизу, используются старые `View`, которые ушли с экрана (которые были сверху). То есть при отображении ячеек , которые появляются снизу, метод `onCreateViewHolder(...)` уже не вызывается, а вызывается только `onBindViewHolder(...)`, который получает одну из уже отрисованных `View`, которую на экране уже не видно, перерисовывает этот `View` и отображает его снизу.

Cуть паттерна `ViewHolder` заключается в том, что он удерживает ссылку на `View`, которая в последствии будет перерисована заново.

А нужно это для **повышения производительности** и экономии памяти, так как если бы Вы каждый раз создавали новую `View`, то каждый раз создавался бы новый объект, при создании которого выполнялся бы метод `findViewById(...)`, который относительно ресурсоемок.

Comment: Спасибо за такой красивый и развернутый ответ! Сразу, конечно, выглядит крайне непонятным... Буду завтра пробовать ставить. Правда пока не уверен, как сработается с булеан коллекцией. Думалось сразу читать из `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: @Pollux, Ну Вы вполне можете читать из `SharedPreferences` в адаптере. Если что-то будет непонятно – пишите.

Comment: Я бы кончено поправил немного, но очень люблю развернутые и оформленные ответы. более чем+

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, А что не так?

Comment: @post_zeew, Ваш пример работает, спасибо большое! Но, к сожалению, присутствует та же самая "аномалия". Если сделать сетку достаточно большой, чтоб можно было прокрутить (~150 итемов) и, для проверки эффекта, в `onBindViewHolder` вместо `holder.mButton.setText("Unlocked");` установить `holder.mButton.setText(String.valueOf(position));` и убрать в `else` `holder.mButton.setText("Locked");`, то опять начинаются случайные повторения при прокрутке вниз-вверх =(

Comment: @Pollux, У меня ничего не дублируется: http://savepic.ru/12040607.gif

Comment: @post_zeew, Вы установили номера на все элементы. Установите номера только на разблокированные кнопки (в Вашем примере это первые 10).

Comment: @Pollux, В этом случае *аномалия* начинается из-за того, что при попытке отрисовки очередного `view`, Вам возвращается старый `view` (который ранее уже был отрисован), и если Вы его не измените, он таким и останется. Перерисовка в данном случае будет только при выполнении `mLevels.get(position) == true`, в противном случае мы отрисуем старую `view` но уже на новом месте. Чтобы избавиться от этой проблемы обработайте случай, когда `mLevels.get(position) == false` например таким образом `holder.mButton.setText("");`. Почитайте про паттерн `ViewHolder`, станет немного понятнее.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду как-то пробовать

Comment: @Pollux, Смотрите **UPD**, я там про `ViewHolder` написал.

Comment: Учел Ваши замечания и, вроде как, даже получилось желаемое) Спасибо огромное Вам за помощь! Остался небольшой вопросик: в `MainActivity` в строке `mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 4));` цифра 4 указывает на кол-во столбцов в сетке. А есть ли параметр наподобии `auto_fit` как в `gridView`? Т.к. на больших экранах может поместится больше элементов.

Comment: @Pollux, Насколько я знаю, такого конструктора нет, но Вы можете самостоятельно рассчитать кол-во столбцов в зависимости от ширины экрана, например, [так](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38472370).

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделаю!

Comment: Зачем использовать `RelativeLayout` для такой простой разметки - возможности этого контейнера никак не используются, зато он гораздо "тяжелее" того же `LinearLayout`, что скажется на производительности, тем более в прокручиваемых списках.

Comment: @pavlofff, как раз надо было отцентрировать элементы, а то левее были немного, заменил на `LinearLayout`. Визуально всё осталось так же, к тому же, как Вы сказали, лучше производительность будет.

Comment: @pavlofff, Незачем :) В этом согласен. Обновил ответ.